# What does call.call accomplish in javascript

Tags: javascript, modernizr

Found this excerpt in the Modernizr source code.

```
var documentCreateElement = scopeDocument.createElement, documentCreateDocumentFragment = scopeDocument.createDocumentFragment;

// shiv the document
for (var i = 0, elements = html5.elements, l = elements.length; i < l; ++i) {
     call.call(documentCreateElement, scopeDocument, elements[i]);
}

// shiv the document create element method
scopeDocument.createElement = function (nodeName) {
var element = call.call(documentCreateElement, scopeDocument, nodeName);
```

I was wondering why it was necessary to use `call.call`, as opposed to just `call` What is the accomplishing that `documentCreateElement.call(scopeDocument,nodeName)` does not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Surely this depends on what `call` is? `documentCreateElement.call(...)` calls `documentCreateElement`; but `call.call` calls `call`, so `call.call(documentCreateElement,...)` only calls `documentCreateElement` *if* `call` is `Function.prototype.call` -- which, despite its name, it might not be.

Comment: (To make this a bit less opaque: suppose that the code was `CALL.call(documentCreateElement, ...)`. Would you still assume that it's equivalent to `documentCreateElement.call(...)`? Well, just because the variable `CALL` has been renamed to `call`, that still doesn't necessarily mean that it's a copy of the `call` method off a function object.)

Comment: @ruakh Have a look at the [source code](http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-2.5.2.js). `call` --> `Date.call` --> `Function.prototype.call`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it calls the `.call` function from the context of the `documentCreateElement` function.

So ultimately it's the same as...

```
documentCreateElement.call(scopeDocument, nodeName);
```

I assume that there's a reference to `Function.prototype.call` somewhere, like

```
var call = Function.prototype.call
```

<s>They probably cache the `call` method just in case it gets overwritten on `Function.prototype`.</s>

---

***EDIT:***

As [@ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) pointed out below, if `Function.prototype.call` was overwritten, then `call.call` wouldn't work since it also relies on `Function.prototype`.

`documentCreateElement` is a reference to the `document.createElement` method, and that method is a host object, so there's no guarantee that it will include `Function.prototype` in its prototype chain.

This would allow them to use `.call` on host objects in those cases.

Comment: That was kind of my question, " What is that accomplishing that documentCreateElement.call(scopeDocument,nodeName) does not?"  I'm wondering why they choose to use call.call

Comment: Actually, `var call = Date.call;`, which resolves to `Function.prototype.call`.

Comment: @user772110: I updated. I'm guessing it's just in case `Function.prototype.call` is overwritten by some other code.

Comment: @amnotiam: But doesn't `call.call` always call `Function.prototype.call`? It seems like overwriting the latter would break the former as well.

Comment: @ruakh: Yep, you're right. Now I'm not sure why they do that.

Comment: @ruakh: I'll bet it's because it's being used against `document.createElement`, which is a host object/function, so it may not have a `call` method. There's probably some browser that doesn't have `.call()` on its host functions.

Comment: @user772110: I updated my answer with a more plausible explanation as to why they do this.

Answer (score 1):

`call.call` calls the user defined function `call` with a different *context*.

`call` is a native JavaScript function. It's a function you can call on a function, because in JavaScript functions are *first class citizens*, and it's called `call`, which is very confusing :P

The first parameter of `call` is the *context*, whatever `this` should refer to in the called function. Here is an example:

```
function doit() {
    console.log(this.myvalue);
}

function callit(context) {
    doit.call(context);
}

callit({ "myvalue": "a value"});    // a value
var obj = {
    "stuff" : "more stuff",
    "myvalue": "some value"
};
callit(obj);    // some value
```

So `documentCreateElement.call(scopeDocument,nodeName)` basically does `documentCreateElement(nodeName)` but the `this` in `documentCreateElement` points to `scopeDocument`. You can wonder whether the example code you posted is good use of `call`. I always find it very complicated if used wrongly and out of place ~_~